# MAGMA: Excluding LowIndexSubgroups containing some elements

Tags: group-theory, gap, finitely-generated, magma-cas

In the GAP [command](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap47.html#X87FBDA2B815A8776) `LowIndexSubgroupsFpGroup` there is an optional argument, a list of elements of the group, to restrict the search only to subgroups that do not contain any conjugate of any of the elements in the list.

I can't find in the documentation any analogue for the MAGMA [command](https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/663) `LowIndexSubgroups`.

How to do that?

Comment: You could use GAP :-)  But in my experience this is a feature in GAP that does not have a real impact on calculation time. You could as well calculate (in Magma) all subgroups, and then discard those on whose cosets the excluded elements have a fixed point.

Comment: @ahulpke Thanks. How exactly should I discard the unwanted subgroups with MAGMA? Another thing: if I got it, you think that via GAP the computation time would be the same in both ways, i.e. (1) by directly exclude them in the search, or (2) by finding all subgroups and then excluding the unwanted ones. A question: do you think that with procedure (1) MAGMA is anyway faster than GAP or not?

Comment: PS: I absolutely prefer open source, that's why I asked the last question (if the answer is "no", I won't care about MAGMA) :-)

Comment: I am the wrongest person to ask on whether Magma is faster than GAP. As for the timing difference the exclusion makes it a bit faster but not significantly (in the examples I tried). If $U<=G$ and $g\in G$ then (exists $x\in G:g^x\in U\Leftrightarrow$ $g$ has a fix point on the cosets of $U$)